# Наткнулся на странное поведения оператора взятия остатка от деления %

Tags: javascript, c#

Тестил на js и на C#. Шаги для воспроизведения:

Берем 12 % 5 // 2

А теперь 12 % 13 // 12

12 % 14 // 12

12 % 15 // 12

12 % 143324423 // 12

Я так понимаю, логика такая. Берем левый операнд, делим на правый, в точку вызова данной операции возвращается остаток. А как тогда объяснить поведение последнего примера? Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Comment: а что вы там хотели увидеть? 12 / 143324423 = 0 12 - 0*x = 12

Comment: Точно так же как и три примера перед ним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А чем последний пример отличается от  трёх предыдущих? Везде одинаково: 12 = 0*Х + 12 (остаток), где Х больше 12

Comment: Точняк, эта формула все объясняет!Спасибо!